# Running function only after other function finished in jQuery (HTML modals)

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I would be glad if somebody could help me or point me in the right direction. I try to create a function that should show a chain of modals, one after the other after a confirm button has been pressed, using jQuery. It is not working and I must do some basic mistake. I am not too familiar with JS functions.

Here is the main function:

```
$(function () {
    fn1 = show_modal("#modal_1","#overlay_1","#modal_confirm_1")
    fn2 = show_modal("#modal_2","#overlay_2","#modal_confirm_2")

    fn1().done(fn2);
});
```

Here is my show_modal function in another file:

```
var show_modal = function (modal, overlay, input_id) {
    let deferred = $.Deferred();

    $(modal).add($(overlay)).fadeIn("fast", function () {
      });

    $(input_id).click(function () {
        $(modal).add($(overlay)).hide();
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: by this ` should show a chain of modals, one after the other after a confirm button has been pressed,` you mean to say multiple modals must pop when button is pressed.. a'm i right

Comment: I want modal 1 to pop up by using show_modal("#modal_1","#overlay_1","#modal_confirm_1"). The modal has a button to close it, after pressing the button, modal 2 should pop up, and create a chain of dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

After another day of trying I got it to run. I post my result here, so that others can benefit from it. Naming the functions was done in a bad way, they were running immediately, but I wanted a sequential, asynchronous behavior.

I was able to construct a queue of functions (that run one after the other) with the following code:

```
$(function () {

    var show_modal_1 = show_modal_scaffold("#modal_1","#overlay_1","#modal_confirm_1");
    var show_modal_2 = show_modal_scaffold("#modal_2","#overlay_2","#modal_confirm_2");
    var show_modal_3 = show_modal_scaffold("#modal_3","#overlay_3","#modal_confirm_3");

    var tutorial = [show_modal_1,show_modal_2,show_modal_3];

    var q = $.Deferred().resolve();
      while (tutorial.length > 0) {
      q = q.then(tutorial.shift());
    };

});
```

The scaffold for the show_modal functions had to be changed a bit, it looks like the following:

```
show_modal_scaffold = function (arg1,arg2,arg3) {
    return function (modal=arg1, overlay=arg2, input_id=arg3) {
        let deferred = $.Deferred();

        $(modal).add($(overlay)).fadeIn("fast", function () {
        });

        $(input_id).click(function () {
            $(modal).add($(overlay)).hide();
            deferred.resolve();

        });
        return deferred.promise();
    };
};
```

This is the most minimal syntax I could come up with. As I am not familiar with JavaScript I cannot tell if it is the best way of doing it.